# Netbeans doesn't load libraries from Tomcat's %CATALINA_BASE%/lib folder

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, catalina, tomcat9

I have a Tomcat 9 server that runs well being splitted onto CATALINA_HOME (bin, **lib** with tomcat jars) and CATALINA_BASE (another **lib** folder with other jars, webapps and everything else).
CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE are set as global system variables.

I want to repeat this kind of configuration on my development PC (Windows) with Netbeans IDE.
So when I add Tomcat to Netbeans and set location of the CATALINA_HOME with bin and lib folders only, it asks me for CATALINA_BASE, and I set it also.

As a result I see that tomcat loads it's libraries from CATALINA_HOME\lib, but discards libraries located in CATALINA_BASE\lib (projects in Netbeans also don't see libraries from CATALINA_BASE\lib).

If I install Tomcat as a service and run it, it successfully loads all libraries from the both folders.

I thought that maybe I can find some parameter for this within Netbeans server config file:
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\10.0\config\J2EE\InstalledServers\.nbattrs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE attributes PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD DefaultAttributes 1.0//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/attributes-1_0.dtd">
<attributes version="1.0">
    <fileobject name="instance">
        <attr name="admin_port" stringvalue="8005"/>
        <attr name="debug_type" stringvalue="SEL_debuggingType_shared"/>
        <attr name="displayName" stringvalue="Apache Tomcat 9.0.17"/>
        <attr name="httpportnumber" stringvalue="80"/>
        <attr name="instance_id" stringvalue="tomcat90"/>
        <attr name="java_opts" stringvalue="-Xms512m -Xmx512m -verbose:gc -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
        <attr name="java_platform" stringvalue="jdk1.8.0_202"/>
        <attr name="monitor_enabled" stringvalue="false"/>
        <attr name="registeredWithoutUI" stringvalue="false"/>
        <attr name="runningCheckTimeout" stringvalue="2000"/>
        <attr name="timestamp" stringvalue="1553528984776"/>
        <attr name="url" stringvalue="tomcat90:home=C:\dev\srv\apache-tomcat-9.0.17:base=C:\dev\srv\catalina_base"/>
        <attr name="username" stringvalue="tomcatuser"/>
    </fileobject>
</attributes>
```

but I haven't find any option for this.

So the question is: how to configure Netbeans to support libraries from both CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE folders?

Comment: I see this issue in NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 12. Libraries in CATALINA_BASE/lib are not added to the list of those in CATALINA_HOME/lib

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue with Tomcat 8 and 8.5 with NetBeans 8.2 and 12 Ant based projects. I've done a lot of testing and some research. I see a lot of other issue reports related to handling CATALINA_BASE, but not this specifically.

My current solution is to change the CATALINA_HOME directories to be writable by myself and place my libraries to CATALINA_HOME/lib. This is less than ideal because it's not really developing against the deployment environment, but it seems to be a necessary work-around without a code change to NetBeans.

With this setup I'm questioning my use of Catalina Base in my NetBeans Server Tomcat configs. I'm not sure what value it provides except that I noticed that 8.2's bundled Tomcat 8.0 also drops in a CATALINA_BASE/nblib with the httpmonitor and schema2beans libraries.